# How can one resolve the problem regarding the network connection to skype downloaded from snap store behind a proxy server from ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: apt, server, skype, snap, proxy

All other things related to internet, such as browsing, installing, and uninstalling using `sudo` command are working fine. I have provided the proxy server details through `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf`, and also tried both `export http_proxy` and `export https_proxy`.

---